# How to get specific table by current user login

Tags: database, users, wpdb, sql, plugin-contact-form-7

I'm using contact form 7 and "save contact form 7".
I want that the logged user see only his own fields.
So, He'll see results only if `$reservation->user` is equal to `$current_user->user_login`.

By the way, when the user submit the contact form, his user value is automatically generated as the current username.

```
[text* user readonly default:user_login]
```

So, my problem is only when I try to get the table from my database.

I'm using the following code:

```
global $wpdb;

$current_user = wp_get_current_user();
$username     = $current_user->user_login;

echo 'Username: ' . $username . "\n";

$reservations = $wpdb->get_results( "SELECT * FROM SaveContactForm7_1 WHERE user= '***I need the condition here***' ;" );

//print_r( $reservations );
```

For the table that will appear in my page, this is the code:

```
<?php
echo "<table>";
echo "<tr>";
echo "<th>ID</th>";
echo "<th>Nom et Prenom</th>";
echo "<th>Qualite</th>";
echo "<th>Arrivee</th>";
echo "<th>Num Vol</th>";
echo "<th>Heure atterrissage</th>";
echo "<th>Provenance</th>";
echo "<th>Depart</th>";
echo "<th>Num Vol</th>";
echo "<th>Decollage</th>";
echo "<th>Destination</th>";
echo "<th>Hotel</th>";
echo "<th>Type de chambre</th>";
echo "<th>Total a payer</th>";
echo "</tr>";

foreach($reservations as $reservation){
echo "<tr>";
echo "<td>".$reservation->user."</td>";
echo "<td>".$reservation->nom."</td>";
echo "<td>".$reservation->qualite."</td>";
echo "<td>".$reservation->datearrivee."</td>";
echo "<td>".$reservation->num_vol_arrivee."</td>";
echo "<td>".$reservation->heure_atterrissage."</td>";
echo "<td>".$reservation->provenance."</td>";
echo "<td>".$reservation->datedepart."</td>";
echo "<td>".$reservation->num_vol_depart."</td>";
echo "<td>".$reservation->heure_decollage."</td>";
echo "<td>".$reservation->destination."</td>";
echo "<td>".$reservation->choix."</td>";
echo "<td>".$reservation->typech."</td>";
echo "<td>".$reservation->calculated_choix."</td>";
echo "</tr>";
}
echo "</table>";
?>
```

Comment: Is this a contact form 7 question? That database table is non-standard/3rd party, how will we know what its contents/format are? User could be a user ID, or a username, edit your question and let us know

Comment: I edited my question. Yes, I'm using both "contact form 7" and "save contact form 7". Also, I set the user field as default readonly current "user_login" to get automatically the current user_login value. Hope It's clear now. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Note** that you may need to use [`WPDB::prepare()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wpdb/prepare/) to prevent against SQL injections. Although, it might be arguable in your specific case...

```
// If the query does not work, ensure the table name is correct...
$table = $wpdb->prefix . 'SaveContactForm7_1';

$reservations = $wpdb->get_results(
    $wpdb->prepare(
        "SELECT * FROM $table WHERE user = %s",
        $username
    )
);
```

See [`WPDB`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/wpdb) class reference. Hope this answers to your question.